# montando uma RegEx

Tags: asp.net, regex

Estou apanhando um bocado aqui com pra montar o Regex de um padrão que montei, que seria este:

```
ALTERAC[AO,OES] [DE] CADASTRO[S] [-] SOCIAL
```

O que está entre `[ ]` é o que pode variar. A duvida é que nas palavras **"DE"** e **"-"** podem ou não ter, então queria ignora-las. Já tentei de diversas formas mas não está saindo conforme o necessário.

Eis o código que montei:

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            string texto = "alteracao de cadastro social";
            //string texto = "alteracao de cadastro - social";
            //string texto = "alteracoes de cadastro social";
            //string texto = "alteracao cadastro social";
            //string texto = "alteracao cadastro - social";


            bool passou = (new Regex(@"(a)(l)(t)(e)(r)(a)(c)(ao|oes)( )(de)( )(c)(a)(d)(a)(s)(t)(r)(o|os)( )(-)(s)(o)(c)(i)(a)(l)").IsMatch(texto));


            Console.WriteLine(passou);
        }
    }
```

https://dotnetfiddle.net/vhLRaz

Comment: Tente usar o quantificador `?`, que corresponde a zero ou uma vez. [Veja esta referência](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/standard/base-types/quantifiers-in-regular-expressions)

Comment: tentei colocando (no caso do "de") (de?) mas não está ignorando

Comment: Tente `(de)?`. Veja [esta referência com exemplos para entender melhor cada elemento do Regex](http://regexstorm.net/reference)

Comment: tb não funciona! eu estou mais de 1 dia tentando tudo quanto é jeito e isso que não estou conseguindo pra finalizar. é só ignorar a palavra de e o - (mas n posso usar replace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Regex:

Esta é a Regex: `(a)(l)(t)(e)(r)(a)(c)(ao|oes)( )?(de)?( )(c)(a)(d)(a)(s)(t)(r)(o|os)( )?(-)?( )(s)(o)(c)(i)(a)(l|is)`

E a [demo no regexstorm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28a%29%28l%29%28t%29%28e%29%28r%29%28a%29%28c%29%28ao%7coes%29%28+%29%3f%28de%29%3f%28+%29%28c%29%28a%29%28d%29%28a%29%28s%29%28t%29%28r%29%28o%7cos%29%28+%29%3f%28-%29%3f%28+%29%28s%29%28o%29%28c%29%28i%29%28a%29%28l%7cis%29&i=alteracao+de+cadastro+social%0d%0aalteracao+de+cadastro+-+social%0d%0aalteracoes+de+cadastro+social%0d%0aalteracao+cadastro+social%0d%0aalteracao+cadastro+-+social&r=+&o=m).

#### Explicação

- `(a)(l)(t)(e)(r)(a)(c)` - Corresponde literalmente a **alterac**
- `(ao|oes)` - Corresponde literalmente a **ao** ou **oes**
- `( )?` - Corresponde a zero ou uma vez o espaço **( )**
- `(de)?` - Corresponde a zero ou uma vez a palavra **de**
- ( ) - Corresponde literalmente o espaço **( )**
- `(c)(a)(d)(a)(s)(t)(r)` - Corresponde literalmente a **cadastr*
- `(o|os)` - Corresponde literalmente a **o** ou **os**
- `( )?` - Corresponde a zero ou uma vez o espaço **( )**
- `(-)?` - Corresponde a zero ou uma vez o hífen **-**
- `( )(s)(o)(c)(i)(a)` - Corresponde literalmente a **espaço e socia**
- `(l|is)` - Corresponde literalmente a **l** ou **is**

#### Problema

O seu problema é que com esta lógica: `ALTERAC[AO,OES] [DE] CADASTRO[S] [-] SOCIAL` Há dois espaços entre alteracao e cadastro se não houver de, o mesmo ocorre com o hífen.

A lógica utilizada para corrigir é: `ALTERAC[AO,OES][ DE] CADASTR[O|OS][ -] SOCIA[L|IS]`

Comment: poxa vl!!! era um pequeno detalhe !!!